# Why is HubSpot Autogenerating Forms?

Tags: php, forms, api, hubspot

I am submitting a contact form to HubSpot using their api (https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form), which is working out great, except that every time I do it, HubSpot autogenerates a new form in its site under Marketing -> Forms, with a name like #form_5dd7ee368739f.  It says that this is a non-Hubspot form and gives this explanation:

> **What is a non-HubSpot form** 
>   Non-HubSpot forms are HTML forms on your
>   website that weren't created in HubSpot. Based on your settings,
>   data for these forms is automatically collected in HubSpot. Learn
>   more.

"Learn more" isn't a link; I can't click on it.  The submission of the api request is recorded both in this new form that it autogenerated each time the form is submitted, as well as in the form that I built in HubSpot that supposed to handle this request.  Here is my code:

```
<?php
// wp-config.php
define('HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID', getenv('hubspot_portal_id'));
define('HUBSPOT_CONTACT_FORM_GUID', getenv('hubspot_contact_form_guid'));
define('HUBSPOT_CONTACT_FORM_ENDPOINT', "https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/".HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID."/{form_guid}");
?>

<?php
// hubspot.php
function hubspot_form_submit($page_url, $page_name, $endpoint, $data) {
    $hs_context = array(
        'ipAddress' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'pageUrl' => $page_url,
        'pageName' => $page_name,
    );
    if (array_key_exists('hubspotutk', $_COOKIE)) {
        $hs_context['hutk'] = $_COOKIE['hubspotutk'];
    }
    $data['hs_context'] = $hs_context;

    $data_string = "";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_string($value)) {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        else if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = json_encode($value);
        }
        $data_string = $data_string.$key."=".$value."&";
    }
    $data = rtrim($data_string, "&");

    $ch = @curl_init();
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = @curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_error($ch)) {
        $result = curl_error($curl);
    }
    $status_code = @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    @curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
?>

<?php
// contact.php
require_once("inc/hubspot.php");
$hubspot_form_submission = hubspot_form_submit(
    "https://www.example.com/contact/",
    "Contact",
    str_replace("{form_guid}", HUBSPOT_CONTACT_FORM_GUID, HUBSPOT_CONTACT_FORM_ENDPOINT),
    array(
        "firstname" => $form->data["first_name"],
        "lastname" => $form->data["last_name"],
        "email" => $form->data["email"],
        "phone" => $form->data["phone"],
        "preferred_contact_method" => $form->data["contact_method"],
        "message" => $form->data["comments"],
    )
);
?>
```

Anyone know how I can prevent HubSpot from autogenerating these forms?  Otherwise my forms box will quickly become filled up with hundreds of autogenerated forms that I will keep having to delete.  Something to note: the actual form that I created for this purpose is located within a folder, whereas the autogenerated forms are always located outside of any folders, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I considered that, and something like that is probably the case, but it is recording the submission for the form that I created, so it is finding that form and doing exactly what it is supposed to; it is just creating this new form on the side every time.  Yes, I have checked that the constants contain the correct values.  Everything appears to be in order as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the client had enabled the use of Non-HubSpot forms in their settings, so all that is required to fix it is just to turn this functionality off.  The documentation is here:

https://knowledge.hubspot.com/forms/use-non-hubspot-forms

The setting is located in

Settings -> Marketing -> Forms -> Non-HubSpot Forms